# Differential equation with one variable.

Tags: calculus

I am trying to solve an equation with a single variable $x$.
It is for calculating the frequency of a harmonic oscillator.
I am trying to solve it on my [TI-Nspire CX CAS](https://education.ti.com/en/products/calculators/graphing-calculators/ti-nspire-cx-cas?category=resources) with `deSolve` but it keeps giving me the error that I have too few arguments.

> The equation:
> $$mx''+kx+yx'=0$$
>
> With: $k=4.42\cdot 10^8, \ y=10^{-2}$ and $m=0.007$.

Substituting gives:
$$0.007x''+(4.42\cdot 10^8)x+10^{-2}\cdot x'=0$$

Apparently my teacher did the following in Wolfram:
$$\text{equation = } \ m x''[t] + \text{gamma } x'[t] + k x[t] ⩵ 0.$$

How can I reproduce this on my TI-Nspire?

Comment: You can also solve the equation without a computer. Consider a function of the type $e^{zx}$ for z possibly complex.

Comment: but the quadratic formula would be SOOOOO ugly @J.P.C.

Comment: @J.P.C. In that case, it would be $e^{z\color{red}{t}}$ since $t$ is the independent variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `deSolve`, one can solve this differential equation using the [calculator](https://education.ti.com/en/products/calculators/graphing-calculators/ti-nspire-cx-cas?category=resources) using two different approaches. Here is a screenshot I took upon using an emulator of the TI-Nspire CX CAS:

**Approach 1: Direct substitution of constants**

[image]

**Approach 2: Previously defining constants**

[image]

---

In $\LaTeX$, this result is:
$$x(t)=c_1\cdot (0.489542)^t\cdot \cos(251282\cdot t)+c_2\cdot (0.489542)^t\cdot \sin(251282\cdot t) \tag{1}$$
[Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0.007x%27%27%2B(4.42*10%5E8)*x%2B10%5E(-2)*x%27%3D0) suggests a slightly different result:
$$x(t)=c_1 e^{-0.714286t}\cdot \sin(251282\cdot t)+c_2e^{-0.714286t}\cdot \sin(251282\cdot t) \tag{2}$$
However, note that $(1)$ and $(2)$ are equivalent. This is because $c_1$ and $c_2$ are arbitrary constants and also because of the following identity:
$$e^{ab}\equiv \left(e^a\right)^b \implies e^{-0.714286t}=(e^{-0.714286})^t\approx (0.489542)^t$$

---

Note that it is also easy to solve without using a CAS. One can use the ansatz $x=e^{\lambda t}$ to obtain the characteristic polynomial:
$$0.007\cdot \lambda^2+10^{-2}\cdot \lambda+(4.42\times 10^8)=0$$
One will notice that upon solving for $\lambda$, the roots will be [complex](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/ComplexRoots.aspx).

Comment: Hi projectilemotion, first of all I would like to thank your for your help!

Unfortunately I run into another problem if reproduce the exact same equation with both methods I end up with the following answer:

$$x=c1*(0.489542)^t*cos(1.43974E7*t)+c2*(0.489542)^t*sin(1.43974E7*t)$$

I've already tried resetting the stored variables and changing from degrees to radians.

Comment: yeah I've just tried that by changing the document settings and recalculating the equation but I end up with the same results.
Could it have something to do with the real or complex setting?

Comment: I am pretty sure it has to do with the calculator being in degrees because: $$1.43974\times 10^7\cdot \frac{\pi}{180}\approx 251282$$Try and change the settings from degrees to radians using [this](https://epsstore.ti.com/OA_HTML/csksxvm.jsp?nSetId=99182). From experience, I see that a lot of people do not select "Keep Default". I doubt it has to do with the real/complex setting.

Comment: Ah yes that fixed it I pressed the ok button but that wouldn't safe the settings. Many thanks again!